# Each icon at top of <td>

Tags: html, css, image

**SOLVED by P. Leger:
In my CSS I simply added/changed the vertical-align to top.
This worked for me**

I am developing a simple schedule where the admin can manage users and add users to a specific date.

I want the '+' icon at the top of `<td>` inside a `<table>`. 
Because if there are 3 people planned in on Monday and there are 2 people planned in on thuesday, the icons will be outlined by each other.

This is how it is right now:
[image: You see the red line is straight if there are an equally number of values in a table]

You see the red line is straight if there are an equally number of values in a table

This is how I want it (photoshopped):
[image]

The red lines are in all rows straight.
The red lines are just an indication on how I want it to be (because in real they aren't there of course).

My code right now inside the `<td></td>`:

```
echo '<a href="../rooster/add_rooster.php?week='.$weekrow.'&day='.$day.'&daynmb='.$day_numb.'"><img src="../rooster/images/add.png" width="15" align="left" class="imgtable"></a><br/>
</div>';
```

And the class imgtable:

```
.imgtable {
    float:top;      
}
```

I tried every position and float. But I just need something that the image is fixed inside the table.

Currently I am just using a simple image, but I prefer using a font awesome icon.

I hope that you will understand my question.
Thanks for reading

Comment: The reason i guess is you have each `td` with `vertical-align:middle;`. So give `vertical-align:top;` to image class.

Comment: Could you provide us live/demo.

Comment: it is not really possible to provide a live demo because it is already implented in a full working login system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `float: top`.

> float:  left | right | none | inherit

I think, you don't want the `<a ...><img src=... /></a>` fixed, but at the **top** of `<td>`. Therefore you have to access the `<table>` **id** or **class**. And from there the `<td>`. And set `vertical-align: top`.

**HTML**

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>box</td>
        ...
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#myTable td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nxv5rbh0/1/)

Comment: Worked perfectly for me! Thanks for answering

Answer (score 1):

Just position the icon absolutely and make sure the cell (, or whatever the icon's parent is) is positioned relatively. Then you can position the icon with left/right, and top/bottom.

```
<td style="position relative...">
     <img src="..." style="position: absolute; left: 5px; top: 5px">
</td>
```

that should position them all in the same spot relative to their parent (the table cell).

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/silvertail/cej23cbh/

Comment: I tried this but It won't work. The image is still in move whenever a value has been added to the <td></td>